# ReactJS: If undefined how to create a empty array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following onSubmit:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("user")
  .doc(user1)
  .update({
    FieldSet: {
      Field_1: field_1,
      Field_2: field_2,
      Field_3: field_3,
      Field_4: field_4,
      Field_5: field_5,
      id: id
    }
  }, {
    merge: true
  })
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (field_1 == '' && field_2 == "" && field_3 == "" && field_4 == '' && field_5 == "") {
    listItemUser?.map(item => {
      setField_1(item?.FieldSet.Field_1)
      setField_2(item?.FieldSet.Field_2)
      setField_3(item?.FieldSet.Field_3)
      setField_4(item?.FieldSet.Field_4)
      setField_5(item?.FieldSet.Field_5)
    })
  }
})
```

When I attempt to update I get a blank screen with the console error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Field_1')

If these fields are undefined within FieldSet (these field wouldn't exist yet) how do I create them and set them to a initial value (ie. 0)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Field_1')` I don't see how this error could come from the code you've shown. Are you sure it's not coming from a different line?

Comment: @NicholasTower - added in other lines - if I remove those useEffect I don't get the error, but then the field does not update

Comment: It looks like `item` does not have a `FieldSet` property, for one of more of the values in `listItemUser`.

Comment: paste the full code for the component. you cannot run the firebase query outside of `useEffect` or an event handler